# Batch file stop executing after executing the first command

Tags: batch-file

I have created a a batch script which has following content. But the script terminates after executing the first statement. I have googled a lot but couldn't find anything helpful.However the individual statements can be executed separately.  PFB the script

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
set AWS_SNAPSHOT_KEEP=1

:: Create a file with all attached volumes
::ec2-describe-volumes|find /i "attached">%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt

:: Create snapshot for this volume
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do ec2-create-snapshot %%s

:: Find old snapshots for this volume.
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=%%s">%EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt

::Copy Snapshot across multiple regions.
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt) do ec2-copy-snapshot -r us-west-2 -s %%s -region us-east-1 

:: Loop over old snapshots, skip the first 1, delete the rest
for /f "tokens=2 skip=%AWS_SNAPSHOT_KEEP%" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\snapshots.txt) do ec2-delete-snapshot %%s
```

Thanks and regards,
Jyoti

Comment: Have you tried putting `echo`s in to see how far it gets?

Comment: @DwayneTowell :It executes only the first statement ie for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do ec2-create-snapshot %%s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ec2-create-snapshot` and friends are themselves batch scripts, if they are the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) that I found online. They happen to call `exit` when they are done. This is exiting your batch script as well.

Instead, try using `call` before the ec2 commands.

`for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do` **`call`** `ec2-create-snapshot %%s`

Apply as needed to the other ec2 commands.

For details see the output of `help exit` and `help call`.

A common idiom to sleep in batch is to ping the local machine:

```
@ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > NUL
```

This "sleeps" for about 2 * 1000 milliseconds = 2 seconds by pinging the local machine twice with a delay of 1 second between each. Add this as needed.

Comment: yeah now its working, also can u tell me how can I insert a wait between these statements??

Comment: okay thanks a bunch. :) :) Can you also tell me that its printing the first few statemennts on console how can I remove those and add my comments ??

Comment: These are all different questions. Have you tried searching for them? That will be faster than asking here. If that doesn't work, you likely want to ask a *new* question on the *new* topic.